# How react.js managed to use a CSS file imported into a JavaScript file (component)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I asked myself this question but after some research on the internet I could not find any answer.

Something like this:

```
import './styles.css';
```

in this:

```
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Someone here to help me?

Comment: That is the feature of webpack, when you build, create react app (or other engine you use) calls webpack, which creates a bundle with all that includes you use in your files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a feature of the bundler your React app is using, like Webpack. See [how Webpack enables importing CSS](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css).

The example on Webpack's documentation looks something like the below snippet (I made some changes for clarity). Keep in mind that Webpack does not know what JSX is (that is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/)'s job), so this uses vanilla DOM nodes.

##### src/style.css

```css
.hello {
  color: red;
}
```

##### src/index.js

```js
import './style.css';

function myComponent() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');

  element.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
  element.classList.add('hello');

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

When you build your React application, Webpack takes all the styles in `src/style.css`, minifies them, and appends a link to the minified stylesheet inside the `head` tag of `build/index.html`.

So in your `build/index.html`, you would see something like the below `link` tag. You can also see this in the DOM with your inspector when you start the application.

##### build/index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  ...
  <link href="/static/css/main.ac7c7319.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
  ...
</head>

<body>
  ...
</body>

</html>
```

Of course the above file will also be minified, so it will not be so easy to read.

This is all made possible through Webpack's dependencies: [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) and [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/).

##### Closing thoughts

It is worth noting that CSS is never actually imported into JavaScript. As [Create React App's documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/) explains,

> Webpack offers a custom way of 'extending' the concept of `import` beyond JavaScript.

So it is not actually a real `import` at all (which normally functions like `require()`).

Answer (score 2):

React doesn't. That transformation is performed by a bundler such as [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/css.html) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) which are tools designed to take web page dependencies and rewrite them into browser-compatible forms.

Comment: but import is going to be part of some ES at some point right? I believe in that case we still need webpack to collect the files statically while standard import will do it dynamically?

Comment: Any `import` statements not used to load JS modules will be rewritten by the bundler before they reach a JS compiler (JS can't import things which aren't JS modules). Even ones which are used to load JS will tend to be rewritten too.